# How would i add a key:value pair to a json list in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fs

I am using node.js, and i want to add the arguments from a command and the server id as a key:value pair into a json file like this:

```js
{

    "guildid": "args",
    "guildid2": "args2",

}
```

And the current code that i have is far from what i want, where this code:

```js
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');

if (command === 'setup') {
const guildid = message.guild.id
        const data = { 
            [guildid]: `${args}`
            }
        const groupname = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        fs.writeFile('./groups.json', groupname,{flags: "a"}, finished);
        function finished(err) {
            message.channel.send(`Success! Your group, **${args}**, has been registered to **${message.guild.name}**`
            )}
```

Outputs what i want to the json file, but if i run the command again it just appends to the end:

```js
{
  "guildid": "args"
}{
  "guildid2": "args2"
}
```

I understand now that using the a flag just appends to the end no matter what and const data is what is giving it the brackets, but i want to know how to be able to format it in the way i showed at the beginning. Apologies for any glaring errors i have made, this is one of my first times using javascript and node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the original file first using [`fs.readFile[Sync]`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and then add on the property as you would any other object:

```js
obj.key = 'value';

// or in your case:
obj[key_variable] = 'value';
```

You should also omit the `'a'` flag as it will append another object (resulting in a syntax error) instead of modifying the one already there. Your code should look like this:

```js
const guildid = message.guild.id;
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/groups.json'));

/* 
  You could either use:
  data[guildid] = `${args}`;

  OR, when stringifying to the file:
  const groupname = JSON.stringify({ 
    ...data, 
    [guildid]: `${args}` 
  }, null, 2);

  Either way will work
*/ 

data[guildid] = `${args}`;
const groupname = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

// remove { flags: 'a' }
fs.writeFile('./groups.json', groupname, finished);

// you should probably write some error handling
function finished(err) {
 message.channel.send(
  `Success! Your group, **${args}**, has been registered to **${message.guild.name}**`
 );
}
```